# SQL Server 2008 Resource Management - By User/Group/Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to put a ceiling on the amount of CPU a certain database or preferably a certain user, or group of users can use?

I have one app on a server that is maxing out the CPU due to complex queries that are being created at runtime.  Until the specific module in that application is redeveloped (which could take months) i need to find a way to stop that specific application from choking SQL Server and reducing availability for other apps on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you look at Resource Governor?  It makes possible to devde the resources between the group of users.

This is only example and for full information you need to look at documentation:

- Create the pools:

  ```
  create resource pool Pool1
   with (
     min_cpu_percent = 30
    , max_cpu_percent = 100
  )


  create resource pool Pool2
   with (
    min_cpu_percent = 50
   , max_cpu_percent = 70
  )


  create resource pool Pool3
   with (
   min_cpu_percent = 5
   , max_cpu_percent = 100  
  )
  ```
- Create the workload groups and link them to pools:

  ```
  create workload group Group1
  using Pool1


  create workload group Group2
  using Pool2


  create workload group Group3
  using Pool3
  ```
- Create the function which will be make decision which workload group will be used for current session:

  ```
  create function dbo.rg_class_simple() returns sysname
     with schemabinding 
   as begin
    declare
     @grp_name as sysname


    if (suser_name() = 'user1')
       set @grp_name = 'Group1'


    else if (suser_name() = 'user2')
       set @grp_name = 'Group2'


    else if (suser_name() = 'user3')      
       set @grp_name = 'Group3'


   return @grp_name


  end
  ```

Comment: Worth noting that Resource Governor is only available on Enterprise edition.